# Upload image to facebook using the Python API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

I have searched the web far and wide for a still working example of uploading a photo to facebook through the Python API ([Python for Facebook](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk)). Questions like this have been asked on stackoverflow before but non of the answers I have found work anymore.

What I got working is:

```
import facebook as fb

cfg = {
    "page_id"      : "my_page_id",
    "access_token" : "my_access_token"
    }

api = get_api(cfg)
msg = "Hello world!"
status = api.put_wall_post(msg)
```

where I have defined the *get_api(cfg)* function as this

```
graph = fb.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'], version='2.2')

# Get page token to post as the page. You can skip
# the following if you want to post as yourself.
resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
page_access_token = None
for page in resp['data']:
    if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
        page_access_token = page['access_token']
graph = fb.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
return graph
```

And this does indeed post a *message* to my *page*.
However, if I instead want to upload an image everything goes wrong.

```
# Upload a profile photo for a Page.
api.put_photo(image=open("path_to/my_image.jpg",'rb').read(), message='Here's my image')
```

I get the dreaded *GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file* for which non of the solutions on stackoverflow works for me.
If I instead issue the following command

```
api.put_photo(image=open("path_to/my_image.jpg",'rb').read(), album_path=cfg['page_id'] + "/picture")
```

I get *GraphAPIError: (#1) Could not fetch picture* for which I haven't been able to find a solution either.

Could someone out there please point me in the right direction of provide me with a currently working example? It would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: The image has to be a file object not it's context and also your line contains a faulty single quotation mark. Without having tested it your should try: `api.put_photo(image=open("path_to/my_image.jpg",'rb'), message='Here\'s my image')`.

Comment: @KlausD.
Yeah, I saw my faulty quotation mark the moment I posted the question, but then it was too late. However, in my real code I have no such marks.

If I try your suggestion
api.put_photo(image=open("path_to/my_image.jpg",'rb'), message='Any message')

I still get *GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file*

But thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Can you list the file and the directory structure you are working with and where your python call starts in which dir

Comment: @phwd 
I have my main.py file in the same folder where I have my facebook folder (copied from the git page for Python for Facebook)
Furthermore, I write the full path to my image, as such:
"Drive:/folder/folder/image.jpg"

As such, I my work folder contains the following

main.py
image.jpg
facebook (folder)

the facebook folder contains

__init__.py
version.py

Hope that helps!

Comment: Try `curl -F 'source=@my_image.jpg' 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN'` in the same folder as the image. If it still returns the 324 error, the problem is the photo.

Comment: @phwd You saved the day! Thank you !!

Your hint about "the problem is the photo" made me recheck my actual image.. Turned out it was corrupt and replacing it with a proper one solved my issue. Your curl expression works as well but shows my personal page being the uploader while the (now working) Python shows my artificial app as the uploader. 

To summarise: I use the script in the original question *without* .read() and everything works as expected. Thank you all for your help. pwhd I don't know how to accept your answer. Maybe I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I only posted a comment earlier, I have added an answer for future visitors below now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 324 Facebook error can result from a few things depending on how the photo upload call was made

- a missing image
- an image not recognised by Facebook
- incorrect directory path reference

A raw cURL call looks like

`curl -F 'source=@my_image.jpg' 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN'`

As long as the above calls works, you can be sure the photo agrees with Facebook servers.

An example of how a 324 error can occur

`touch meow.jpg`

`curl -F 'source=@meow.jpg' 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN'`

This can also occur for corrupted image files as you have seen.

Using `.read()` will dump the actual data

Empty File

```
>>> image=open("meow.jpg",'rb').read()
>>> image
''
```

Image File

```
>>> image=open("how.png",'rb').read()
>>> image
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00...
```

Both of these will not work with the call `api.put_photo` as you have seen and Klaus D. mentioned the call should be without `read()`

So this call

`api.put_photo(image=open("path_to/my_image.jpg",'rb').read(), message='Here's my image')`

actually becomes

`api.put_photo('\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00...', message='Here's my image')`

Which is just a string, which isn't what is wanted.

One needs the image reference `<open file 'how.png', mode 'rb' at 0x1085b2390>`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and doesn't answer the question with the specified API, however, I came upon this via a search and hopefully my solution will help travelers on a similar path.

### Using `requests` and `tempfile`

A quick example of how I do it using the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) modules.

#### Download an image and upload to Facebook

The script below should grab an image from a given url, save it to a file within a temporary directory and automatically cleanup after finished.

> In addition, I can confirm this works running on a Flask service on Google Cloud Run. That comes with the container runtime contract so that we can *store the file in-memory*.

```py
import tempfile
import requests

# setup stuff - certainly change this
filename = "your-desired-filename"           
filepath = f"{directory}/{filename}"
image_url = "your-image-url"
act_id = "your account id"
access_token = "your access token"

# create the temporary directory
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
directory = temp_dir.name

# stream the image bytes
res = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
# write them to your filename at your temporary directory 
# assuming this works
# add logic for non 200 status codes
with open(filepath, "wb+") as f:
        f.write(res.content)

# prep the payload for the facebook call           
files = {
    "filename": open(filepath, "rb"),
}
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{act_id}/adimages?access_token={access_token}"
# send the POST request
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
res.raise_for_status()
if res.status_code == 200:
    # get your image data back
    image_upload_data = res.json()
    temp_dir.cleanup()
    if "images" in image_upload_data:
        return image_upload_data["images"][filepath.split("/")[-1]]
    return image_upload_data
temp_dir.cleanup() # paranoid: just in case an error isn't raised
```